# How to take the derivative of something with respect to something else?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Just when I thought I understood taking derivatives, a textbook example of taking a derivative the equation $$[x(t)]^2+4000^2=[s(t)]^2$$ with respect to time shows that the derivative is $$x\frac{dx}{dt} = s\frac{ds}{dt}$$
However, after  applying the power rule and the chain rule, I come up with $$2x(t)\cdot x'(t)=2s(t)\cdot s'(t)$$.
What concept am I missing about taking the derivative with respect to time? To elaborate a bit, I'm confused as to where the $\mathbf{x}$ and the $\mathbf{s}$ come from in $$\mathbf{x}\frac{dx}{dt} = \mathbf{s}\frac{ds}{dt}$$ from the example. Furthermore, to me it seems like they forgot to apply the power rule.

Example: An Airplane Flying at a Constant Elevation https://cnx.org/contents/i4nRcikn@3.7:74vQD30u@6/Related-Rates

Comment: $x'(t)$ is the same as $\frac{dx}{dt}$, so the difference between the two expressions is just a multiple of $2$.  Perhaps you can elaborate on what's confusing (there might a deeper confusion that you haven't put into words that you're trying to get at).

Comment: $$x^{2} = x \cdot x \implies (x^{2})' = (x \cdot x)' = \underbrace{x' \cdot x + x \cdot x'}_{\text{product rule}} = 2x x'$$ Similarly for $(s^{2})'$. So your equation becomes $$2xx' = 2ss' \implies xx' = ss'$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing anything.

$$2x(t)\cdot x'(t)=2s(t)\cdot s'(t)$$

$$ \iff x(t)\cdot x'(t)=s(t)\cdot s'(t)$$

$$\iff x\frac{dx}{dt} = s\frac{ds}{dt}$$

They divided by $2$ and used the $ \frac{dx}{dt}$ for $x'(t)$.

Comment: Nu the same notions, we often write d/dx for f’(x). Is this really df/dx?

Comment: Yes $(d/{dx})f =\frac {df}{dx} = f'(x)$